# Likelihood of a linear model in matrix form

Tags: machine-learning, probability, conditional-probability, likelihood, covariance-matrix

I have difficulty finding the likelihood of the data represented in the matrix form. The mapping between target variable $\mathbf{T}$ and observed variable $\mathbf{X}$ is given as $f:\mathbf{X}\rightarrow \mathbf{T}$ where the matrix $\mathbf{X}=[\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_N]$ and matrix $\mathbf{T}=[\mathbf{t}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{t}_N]$.

Consider the linear model
$\mathbf{t}_i = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}_i+\mathbf{e}$, where $\mathbf{e}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\sigma^2\mathbf{I})$. Given this information, how do we evaluate the likelihood of the data $p(\mathbf{T}|\mathbf{X},\mathbf{W})$.

My approach: Since $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{W}$ are deterministic quantities, we have mean $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{t}_i]=\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}_i$ and covariance $\mathbb{Cov}[\mathbf{t}_i] = \sigma^2\mathbf{I}$. Since $\mathbf{e}$ follows a Gaussian distribution, therefore, $\mathbf{t}_i$ will also be Gaussian distributed. Hence,
$$p(\mathbf{t}_i|\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{W})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{D/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{t}_i-\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}_i)^T\sigma^{-2}\mathbf{I}(\mathbf{t}_i-\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}_i)} $$where $D$ is dimension of $\mathbf{x}_i$.

Finally, considering independence of data, the likelihood can be expressed as
$$p(\mathbf{T}|\mathbf{X},\mathbf{W}) =\prod_{i=1}^{N}p(\mathbf{t}_i|\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{W})\\= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{ND/2}|\Sigma|^{N/2}}e^{{-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} (\mathbf{t}_i-\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}_i)^T\sigma^{-2}\mathbf{I}(\mathbf{t}_i-\mathbf{W}\mathbf{x}_i)}} $$

I was wondering if somebody can kindly comment if this is the right approach.

Many thanks in advance!!